# Forma femminile di pugile

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Leggendo un articolo che parlava dell'atleta [Irma Testa](http://corrieredelmezzogiorno.corriere.it/napoli/sport/16_aprile_15/campana-irma-testa-va-rio-prima-pugilatrice-azzurra-giochi-a1970730-0309-11e6-8e3c-64e4c3f58891.shtml) gli autori si riferiscono a lei con il termine ***pugilatrice***, mentre io avrei semplicemente usato il termine **pugile**.

> La **pugile** Irma Testa

Su alcuni siti ho trovato il termine pugilatrice come femminile di pugilatore, omologo del termine pugile.

Non credo che sia ammissibile il termine ***pugilessa***.

Qual è la forma corretta?

Comment: Non ho capito il dubbio: al maschile ci sono due possibili termini, “pugile” e “pugilatore”, e ognuno ha il suo femminile, rispettivamente “pugile” e “pugilatrice”. Cosa mi sfugge?

Comment: Semplicemente non conoscevo il termine pugilatrice e mi suonava strano, visto che non mi sembra di uso comune. Istintivamente avrei usato la pugile

Comment: In effetti anch'io avrei avuto qualche dubbio, ma il Treccani [lo riporta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pugilatore).

Comment: Grazie per la precisazione.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In italiano esistono, al maschile, i due termini pressoché equivalenti “[pugile](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pugile)” e “[pugilatore](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pugilatore)” (a volte si usano anche l'anglismo *boxer* e il francesismo *boxeur*). Il femminile del primo è uguale al maschile, “pugile”, mentre il femminile del secondo è “pugilatrice”. Si possono quindi usare entrambi i termini, e se uno o l'altro suona insolito sarà solo perché il pugilato è, e soprattutto era, praticato in misura molto maggiore dai maschi.

Answer (score 2):

In un altro [articolo](http://www.cosmopolitan.it/lifecoach/interviste/a113895/olimpiadi-2016-irma-testa-intervista-pugilato/), dove si parlava di Irma Testa, ho trovato: "alla pugile". Inoltre secondo le regole della lingua italiana, è maschile o femminile a seconda che si riferisca a uomo o a donna.